# Consumo Combustible C++

Tags: c++

No entiendo por que al contestar la pregunta del tanto por ciento se me avanza el programa, en cambio si contesto pero sin el % simplemente consigo una respuesta idonea, estara mal la formula quizas? Gracias de antemano!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float litrosDeposito, consumoCoche, kmTotales;
    int porcentajeRestante;

    cout << "De cuanto es el deposito de combustible de vuestro coche? \n";
    cin >> litrosDeposito;
    cout << "Y cuanto porcentaje os queda? 100%, 75%, 50% o 25%? \n";
    cin >> porcentajeRestante;
    cout << "Cuantos KM haces con un litro de combustible? \n";
    cin >> consumoCoche;

    kmTotales = consumoCoche * litrosDeposito - porcentajeRestante;

    if (kmTotales > 200)
    {
        cout << "Tira millas! \n";
    }
    else if (kmTotales == 200)
    {
        cout << "Por los pelos, pero llegamos! \n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Pasa por caja y llena el deposito! \n";
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Si haces que el porcentaje sea lo último que se pregunta, todo funciona bien, con y sin símbolo de `%`

```
cout << "De cuanto es el deposito de combustible de vuestro coche? \n";
cin >> litrosDeposito;
cout << "Cuantos KM haces con un litro de combustible? \n";
cin >> consumoCoche;
cout << "Y cuanto porcentaje os queda? 100%, 75%, 50% o 25%? \n";
cin >> porcentajeRestante;
```

¿Por qué sucede esto? El flujo de entrada (`std::cin`) cuando lee en valores numéricos lee números hasta que encuentra un dato no numérico, en es momento deja de leer. Esto significa que al leer `12%` el puntero de lectura se queda después del `2`:

Antes (leído en `porcentajeRestante`: nada):

```
Posición del búfer: | 0 | 1 | 2 |
                    +---+---+---+
Datos del búfer:    | 1 | 2 | % |
                    +---+---+---+
Puntero de lectura: | ^ |   |   |
```

Después (leído en `porcentajeRestante`: `12`):

```
Posición del búfer: | 0 | 1 | 2 |
                    +---+---+---+
Datos del búfer:    | 1 | 2 | % |
                    +---+---+---+
Puntero de lectura: |   |   | ^ |
```

Cuando intenta leer el siguiente dato (supongamos que es `20`), lo primero que se encuentra es el `%` que como no es un valor numérico, no lee:

Antes (leído en `consumoCoche`: nada):

```
Posición del búfer: | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
                    +---+---+---+---+---+
Datos del búfer:    | 1 | 2 | % | 2 | 0 |
                    +---+---+---+---+---+
Puntero de lectura: |   |   | ^ |   |   |
```

Después (leído en `consumoCoche`: **nada**, `%` no es un número):

```
Posición del búfer: | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
                    +---+---+---+---+---+
Datos del búfer:    | 1 | 2 | % | 2 | 0 |
                    +---+---+---+---+---+
Puntero de lectura: |   |   |   | ^ |   |
```

Para evitar el problema, puedes cambiar el orden de obtención de datos dejando el porcentaje para lo último o, después de leer el porcentaje, limpiar el búfer:

```
cout << "De cuanto es el deposito de combustible de vuestro coche? \n";
cin >> litrosDeposito;
cout << "Y cuanto porcentaje os queda? 100%, 75%, 50% o 25%? \n";
cin >> porcentajeRestante;

if (cin.peek() == '%') // Si el siguiente dato es un '%', lo ignoramos.
    cin.ignore(1);

cout << "Cuantos KM haces con un litro de combustible? \n";
cin >> consumoCoche;
```

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que si le agregas el % la variable deja de ser numérica y pasa a ser alfanumérica, lo que impide que se pueda realizar la operación de resta sobre la misma.

Creo que lo mejor sería que valides lo ingresado por el usuario, algo así:

```
while (!(cin >> porcentajeRestante))
    cout << "Por favor ingrese un valor numérico\n";
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: El requisito del ejercicio es hacerlo solamente con estructuras de decision.. La verdad es que no se me ocurre nada!

Comment: Entonces podrías poner en lugar de un while un if, para que si "cin" te devuelve false decirle al usuario que hay un error por lo ingresado.

Comment: de todas formas no me sale la formula, no entiendo como poder hacer esa operacion! sera que llevo muchas horas delante del ordenador ya y no luzco jajaja!

Comment: `print` no es una función de C++ y Dan ni siquiera la ha estado usando en su código.